# Sum of gcd of n and 2019-n.

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $d_n$ denote the gcd of $n$ and $(2019-n)$.
Find value of $d_1+d_2+\cdots d_{2018}+d_{2019}$

solution:
$(2019-n,n)=(n,2019)$.So we have to find $(2019,1)+(2019,2)+\cdots (2019,2019)$.Now since $2019=3\cdot 673$.So its easy to obtain $6725$ ig.

This is not my solution. But how can I prove it formally?

Comment: Your idea looks right, but you need justifications for all of your steps. For your first step, you need to say: since $\text{gcd}(a,b) = \text{gcd} (a-b,b)$ if $a ≥ b$ by Euclid's algorithm, substituting $a=2019, b=n$ gives $\text{gcd}(2019,n) = \text{gcd} (2019-n,n)$ (from the question $n≤2019$). Then since only $1, 3, 673, 2019$ are divisors of $2019$ and the rest are coprime pairs, you have to mention $\text{gcd} (p,q)=1$ if $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

Comment: I would rather say: there are $672$ multiples of $3$ between $1$ and $1028$ inclusive, with $\gcd=3$. There are $2$ multiples of $673$ between $1$ and $1028$ inclusive, with $\gcd=673$. There are $2018-672-2=1344$ remaining integers between $1$ and $1028$ inclusive, with $\gcd=1$. And there is $1029$ itself. So the answer is $672\cdot 3+2\cdot 673+1344+2019=6725$. I think this should be rigorous enough for anybody. If you try to justify all your steps, as @TobyMak suggests, then you end up in a (near-)infinite regress.

Comment: I didn't phrase my comment quite right. You should justify the two or three things you have written on your post, but of course not all of the steps. As I said before, the proof looks fine and I find it quite easy to follow. If you add in some theorems it should be rigorous enough for anybody.

Comment: I get it, great explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(n , 2019 - n) = (2019, 2019 - n)$. A simple check gives that $673 \times 3 = 2019$ is the prime factorization of $2019$. Let $L = \sum_{1}^{2019} (2019,i)$.

Once you have this, we notice that only four possible gcds are possible. We break it up : let $S_m = |\{1 \leq n \leq 2019 : (2019 , n) = m\}|$. Then we  get $$
L = 2019S_{2019} + 673S_{673} + 3S_3 + S_1
$$

We now note that all the $S_i$ are sizes of disjoint sets which total to $2019$. With this information, it is trivial to see that $S_{2019} = 1$.

We can explicitly calculate members of $S_{673} $ and $ S_3$. Show yourself that $S_{673} = \{1,...,2019\} \cap \{ 673 | x  , x \neq 2019\}$ like how you usually show containment of sets (and find a similar expression for $S_3$). It is now obvious that $S_{673} = 2 , S_3 = 672$, from which you find $|S_1|$ and finish.